# sql insert statement with a lot of same where clause and one different where cluase

Tags: sql-server

I m sry if the title is not clear.

Here's my proble.

I created a new table which will show total, average and maximum values.

I have to insert the results into that table.

That table will have only 4 rows. No Appointment, Appointment Early, Appointment Late and Appointment Punctual.

So.. I have sth like..

```
insert into newTable
select
'No Appointment' as 'Col1',
avg statement,
total statement,
max statement 
from orgTable
where (general conditions) and (unique condition to check NO APPOINTMENT);
```

I have to do that same thing for another 3 rows.. where only the unique condition is different to check early, punctual or late..

So..the statement is super long.

I wanna reduce the size.. How can I achieve that?

Comment: You need to give us the actual statement are you trying to refactor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Complete proof-of-concept (now in Sql Server), and also we use CTE(the WITH clause) so we don't need to repeat the specific conditions on GROUP BY clause; basically the logic of the program is to tag first the rows where specific condition they belong to, then from there we group them outside of WITH clause.

```
-- drop table attendance;
-- drop table yourtable;
create table attendance
(
arrived datetime
);



declare @d datetime;
set @d = GETDATE();




declare @t integer;
set @t = 0;

while @t < 50 begin

   insert into attendance select dateadd(hour, @t, @d);
   set @t = @t + 1;
end

select * from attendance;


create table yourtable
(
segment varchar(max),
total int,
the_max datetime
);


with tagger as
(
select

    -- specific conditions here
    case 
    when DATEPART(hour,arrived) between 0 and 7 then 
       'First Shift' 
    when DATEPART(hour,arrived) between 8 and 15 then
       'Second Shift' 
    when DATEPART(hour,arrived) between 16 and 23 then
       'Third Shift'         
    else
       'Hurry, inform the programmer of the anomaly!'
    end 
       as segment,

    *

    from attendance
)
insert into yourtable(segment, total, the_max)
select segment, count(*), max(arrived)
from tagger
group by segment;



select * from yourtable
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to reduce the size, really.  SQL statements can get pretty long.

However, once it's run, it's done.  The records will be there, and you can move on.

Is this something that will happen frequently, or in a loop?

Comment: i want to make this sth like a loop. repeating query like that would seem unprofessional.

Comment: @william: manually creating a loop in SQL is even more unprofessional; SQL is **set-based** - it doesn't go well at RBAR (row-by-agonizing-row) operations when you loop over something.... just let SQL do its set-based job and don't worry about that....

Answer (score 1):

Let's take your original statement:

```
insert into newTable
select
'No Appointment' as 'Col1',
avg statement,
total statement,
max statement 
from orgTable
where (general conditions) and (unique condition to check NO APPOINTMENT);
```

Let's hope that `unique condition to check <X>` is simple. We can change your statement to:

```
insert into newTable
select
CASE
    WHEN (unique condition to check NO APPOINTMENT) THEN 'No Appointment'
    WHEN (unique condition to check APPOINTMENT EARLY) THEN 'Early'
    WHEN (unique condition to check APPOINTMENT LATE) THEN 'Late'
    WHEN (unique condition to check APPOINTMENT PUNCTUAL) THEN 'Punctual'
END as 'Col1',
avg statement,
total statement,
max statement 
from orgTable
where (general conditions)
GROUP BY
CASE
    WHEN (unique condition to check NO APPOINTMENT) THEN 'No Appointment'
    WHEN (unique condition to check APPOINTMENT EARLY) THEN 'Early'
    WHEN (unique condition to check APPOINTMENT LATE) THEN 'Late'
    WHEN (unique condition to check APPOINTMENT PUNCTUAL) THEN 'Punctual'
END
```

If these conditions start to look too complex, then you may instead move this case expression into a subselect statement (i.e. your from clause would look something like:

```
from (select col1,col2,col3,<case expression here> as Appointment from orgTable) t
```

And you would then be able to refer to `Appointment` in your `SELECT` and `GROUP BY` clauses.

I'm assuming that all rows in `orgTable` fall into one of these 4 appointment categories. Otherwise, you may need to filter these rows further.

Comment: @william - did you remove the (unique condition) check from your `WHERE` clause - you need to to allow all rows to come through. (I'd initially forgotten to do so in my posted answer, but given it wasn't copy & pastable anyway, I didn't highlight it).

Comment: Yes, I did. But i still get the first line.

Comment: @william - then you may need to post some actual table definitions, sample data, and your actual, current `INSERT` statement. I've tried my best with the abstract descriptions, and the above should return 4 rows (assuming that all 4 conditions are present in your actual data)

Comment: one thing is my conditions are similar conditions.. like.. datediff(second, a, b)>0 and datediff(second, a, b)<20, one condition
datediff(second, a, b)<0 and datediff(second, b, a)<20, one condition
datediff(second, a, b)>0 and datediff(second, a, b)>20, one condition
datediff(second, a, b)<0 and datediff(second, b, a)>20, one condition